# Insert multiple objects with Django

Tags: python, django

I have this simple booking system made with Python/Django and I want my customers to be able to make multiple bookings with my booking form.

Example :

I want to book Room A for 1 night

AND

I want to book Room B for 2 nights (not necessarily the same nights)

AND

I want to book Room C for 1 night

My actual code let me make only one booking at a time, verify if the room is available, calculate the price depending on certain rules (number of nights, base price of the room, weekends, long weekends, holidays).

Here is my models.py : http://pastebin.com/QNpx8SaF

Here is my forms.py : http://pastebin.com/vXvHWyWk

Here is my form template : http://pastebin.com/TsMw71wg

I am not sure how to do this. Should I make a list and store all the bookings ?

How can I add a button in my form to add (n) more bookings and make sure they don't overlap on each other.

Any tips on how the validation and insert should work ? I guess I should validate all the bookings before I insert.

Thanks

Comment: You question is quite broad... Maybe you should try to do your best (read the doc, try code, etc.) then ask specific question about something that does not work in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement formsets (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/) just for create multiple bookings at the same time and probably an add and delete button (https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1389/) to add an delete dynamically new bookins.

You can customise the formset validation for availability and probably change you validation method just for receive an argument with a list of unsaved bookings

Comment: Thanks ! I will try with some formsets, it's strange I didn't land on this before !